# How to write PDP11 style hardware interrupts with priority in 8086?

Tags: assembly, interrupt, x86-16

I apologize ahead if this question sounds a bit lazy. I completed the PDP11 course awhile ago, and I've been asked to help a school student who has trouble with her TASM 8086 project on a very short notice.

I would like to implement a simple program in 8086:

1. A routine that runs with the default priority.
2. A hardware keyboard interrupt routine that runs with priority greater than default.
3. A hardware clock interrupt routine that runs with priority greater than the keyboard interrupt routine.

If you could, please provide a simple working code example. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Interrupts don't work this way on the 8086. It is not really a good idea to copy the way interrupts work on the PDP-11 to the x86 CPU.

Comment: @fuz: Thank you, it's a valuable piece of knowledge that I was missing and it's helpful in search for a solution. +1 for making an effort to answer instead of just voting to close the question. Could you write an answer so I can accept it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 8086 provides software support for up to 256 distinct IRQs numbered 0x00 to 0xff.  For each IRQ, a separate handler is specified in the [interrupt vector table](https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_vector_table).  This doesn't mean that the 8086 CPU has 256 physical interrupt lines though.

In a typical 8086 setup, one or two [8259 programmable interrupt controllers](https://wiki.osdev.org/8259_PIC) (PIC) are used to manage 8 or 15 interrupt lines.  Each PIC has 8 interrupt lines, one line of the first PIC is used to connect the second PIC in a master/slave setup.  When a device sends an interrupt, the PIC causes an IRQ in the CPU with the appropriate IRQ number and your interrupt handler is executed.  Read the linked article for details on how to work with the 8259.

Typical 8086 systems (including the IBM PC and compatible) are designed such that each device has its own IRQ line.  There is no IRQ chaining like on the PDP-11 and there are no IRQ priorities. All the devices you are interested in have fixed interrupt lines assigned to them, [see here](https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupts#Standard_ISA_IRQs) for details.  Note that the IRQ numbers in this diagram are 8259 IRQ numbers, not 8086 IRQ numbers.  The actual 8086 IRQ that is raised depends on how you configure the 8259 PIC.